# flow types and mapping over classes

Tags: flowtype

I'm still getting acclimated to flow, but here is a case I'm a little confused as to how to handle.

I have a few classes that are fired, their "fireScript" method, in a method for a promise.all. I do not know how I would annotate a class as it moves thru a map.

```
import ShoeClass from 'products/ShoeClass';
import HatClass from 'products/HatClass';

//somewhere else the code

await promise.all([ShoeClass, HatClass]
  .map(product => product.firScript()))
```

this is giving me errors, so I am trying to find a generic flow type for a Class, is that even possible?

```
  .map(product <---- this wants an annotation. Each mapped class is different obviously, but how would I annotate it? With a generic?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
await promise.all(
  [ShoeClass, HatClass].map((product: Class<*>):Promises<*> => product.firScript()));
```

There is a cool flowType cheat sheet [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2016/06/flow-type-cheat-sheet/) for quick reference.